# Get values of two keys in JSON array and save them in a seperate array

Tags: php, arrays, json

My JSON Array has 3 keys, like this:

```
        $json = "[{"date":"31-07-2017","time":"15:44","amount":"0"},{"date":"30-07-2017","time":"15:44","amount":"0"},{"date":"01-08-2017","time":"22:33","amount":"40"}]"
```

I am using the following code to extract the keys, i.e the values of amount:

```
$jdec = (json_decode($json, false));    
$jlist1 = array();
$jlist2 = array();
    foreach ($jdec as $element) {
            $jlist[] = $jlist-> amount;
            $jlist2[] = $jlist-> date;
            }
```

But is it possible to extract to key values at once and save it in the same array?

Comment: Why couldn't you save it in the same array? What is your expected output? Inside your loop you should use `$element` in place of `jlist` to get your values. Also, you are saving the amount to an array named `$jlist` but defining `$jlist1` above. You could save the value in the array with the date as the key like: `$jlist[$element->date] = $element->amount;` as long as date doesn't repeat (or you could sum amount if it does). That would probably give you a little better structure to work with.

Comment: this worked, thank you!

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer. I assume it was the last suggestion to nest under the date that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the value in the array with the date as the key like: `$jlist[$element->date] = $element->amount;` as long as date doesn't repeat (or you could sum amount if it does). That would probably give you a little better structure to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jlist[$element->date] = $element->amount;
```

as suggested by Jonathan Kuhn did the job.